# How can I use ansible facts in order to skip execution of some sections?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I want to speed-up ansible playbook execution by avoiding to call some sections that do not have to be called more often than once a day or so.

I know that facts are supposed to allow us to implement this but it seems almost impossible to find some basic example of: setting a fact, reading it and doing something if this it has a specific value, setting a default value for a fact.

```
- name: "do system update"
  shell: echo "did it!"
- set_fact:
    os_is_updated: true
```

If my impression or facts are nothing else than variables that can be saved, loaded and caches between executions?

Let's assume hat `ansible.cfg` is already configured to enable fact caching for two hours.

```
[defaults]
gathering = smart
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_timeout = 7200
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/facts_cache
```

Answer (score 0):

By its nature as a workstation CLI tool, Ansible doesn't have any built-in persistence mechanism (pretty much by design). There are some fact caching plugins that will use external stores (eg, [Redis, jsonfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching)), but I'm not generally a fan.

If you want to persist stuff like that between runs yourself on the target machine(s), you can store them as local facts in /etc/ansible/facts.d (or an arbitrary location if you call setup yourself), and they'll come back from gather_facts under the ansible_local dictionary var. Assuming you're running on a *nix-flavored platform, something like:

```
- hosts: myhosts
  tasks:
  - name: do update no more than every 24h
    shell: echo "doing updates..."
    when: (lookup('pipe', 'date +%s') | int) - (ansible_local.last_update_run | default(0) | int) > 86400
    register: update_result

  - name: ensure /etc/ansible/facts.d exists
    become: yes
    file:
      path: /etc/ansible/facts.d
      state: directory

  - name: persist last_update_run
    become: yes
    copy:
      dest: /etc/ansible/facts.d/last_update_run.fact
      content: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%s') }}"
    when: not update_result | skipped
```

Obviously the facts.d dir existence stuff is setup boilerplate, but I wanted to show you a fully-working sample.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear but I assumed that I do already have the caching configured, so what I am looking is for an example of "do x if x was not already done in the last 2 hours (caching timeout).

Comment: For some reason, set_fact is explicitly not persisted to a fact cache (not sure why). https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/26209342a28ad70775fa303035a12f4ff77c5f2e/lib/ansible/plugins/strategy/__init__.py#L328